# variable for color in latex

Tags: beamer, color, conditionals, naming

I am using beamer for writing my presentation. I was initially using latex+dvipdf, then with the help of other tex.exchange users I recognized that I cannot use transparency in this way. So now I am switching to pdflatex.

Because I use personalized colors and didn't want to use RGB names, I was using names from dvipsnames, but now I have to switch to svgnames, and the color names are of course different. I would like to use a variable that stores the color name, so that I can choose a color to be defined either in svgnames or in dvipsnames, depending if I am using pdflatex or not.

I tried this

```
\ifpdf color1=cyan
\else color1=PineGreen \fi
```

but it doesn't work, what should I do?

Comment: Since `beamer` uses `xcolor`, I suppose that `\colorlet{color1}{cyan}` should work.

Comment: It isn't clear to me why you can't use dvipsnames with pdflatex. Do you have a MWE (ie small complete document that shows the problem)

Comment: @David Carlisle you are right, it works. I must have been mistaken earlier. I suppose I should delete this question? On the other side the question still makes sense, regardless if dvipsnames work or not with pdflatex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can* load the `dvipsnames` option:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
```

Since `beamer` already loads `xcolor` with the `svgnames` option, you can't say 
`\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}` (or `color`); in order to overcome this limitation, one can specify that option to the class.

If you still want to use different colors based on the compiler, then

```
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
  \colorlet{color1}{cyan}
\else
  \colorlet{color1}{PineGreen}
\fi
```

will work.